# Unable to access “895 GB Volume”

Tags: 14.04, mount, ntfs, storage

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/mdnazmossakib/01D189A576840DF0: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/mdnazmossakib/01D189A576840DF0"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

What is the solution to this? It was working fine, but this suddenly happened. Help me to solve this.

Comment: what is unclear about "the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)"? Oh and this is a problem generated by Windows ;)

Comment: i did. so many times

Comment: IMHO you really can not fix this from Ubuntu, you need to boot windows, check the disk, and disable fast boot and hibernation.

Comment: @Nazmos Sakib are you using windows 8 or 10?

Answer (score 0):

@Nazmos Sakib. You can, if you are using windows 8 and that you have shutdown your system completely but still facing the same issue.., go to your power settings and ensure that ***"on shutdown: the machine actually shuts down"*** and does **not hibernate instead**. Then after these settings you can shut down and the power on and log into Ubuntu, and access your drive.